# Trying to understand logic behind this functions

Tags: javascript

I am bit confuse to understand logic of this function

```
function foo(){
  var bar = function() {
    return 3;
  };
  function bar() {
    return 8;
  };
return bar();
}
alert(foo());
```

alert(foo()); print 3. But as per my logic

```
var bar = function() {
    return 3;
  };
```

is local function because of var keyword and

```
function bar() {
    return 8;
  };
```

is global function for function foo(). Also java script execute line by line so the function with same name which call last should print output. So as per my logic this function should print 8. But it is printing 3.

Also the another example

```
function foo(){
  return bar();
  var bar = function() {
    return 3;
  };
  var bar = function() {
    return 8;
  };
}
alert(foo());
```

This function throw error `Uncaught TypeError: bar is not a function` 
Why it is giving error. Can anyone please solve my confusion with both function?
Sorry if my logic goes wrong please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are local. But `function bar` is being *hoisted* (look it up…).

Comment: functions are hoisted before declarations happens.

Comment: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](//stackoverflow.com/q/336859)

Comment: @deceze: I looked at that one, but the `return` screws it up. But Pooja - [Somewhere in here](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+function+hoisting) you'll find the answer to the above, which is that the declaration happens *first*, and then you overwrite the function returning `8` with the one returning `3` afterward.

Comment: @T.J.C I think the top answer explains the basic concept pretty well and can easily be applied here.

Comment: @deceze I understand why first function return 3 but I am still confuse about 2nd function which throw error Uncaught TypeError: bar is not a function

Comment: Because no function is assigned to `bar` by the time you're trying to call it, because assignments are *not* hoisted.